# Crashlytics report not clean

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, crashlytics, crash-reports

[image]

this is a function implementation I cant see anything that make app crash
`

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if scrollView.contentOffset.y <= 0 {
          //reach top
          loggerDebug.info("Scroll view reach to top")
          availableRobomartListTV.isScrollEnabled = false
          // Add gesture to view if scroll reach to top
          view.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
        }
     }
```

`

Comment: Please see if availableRobomartListTV and view {view.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)} are in memory. If they are not in memory there is high chance the code is crashing because of that.

Comment: I think your gesture is adding multiple times in this function. can you please review your code one more time and print the added gesture count.

Comment: Chirag Sondagar yes it is adding multiple times but it is not crashing

Comment: can it be mamory lake issue?

Comment: For the crash report, this is why it may be showing large line numbers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65334819/4044241