# Firebase Crashlytics for iOS shows just strange crashes

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, crashlytics, enterprise

I tried to setup Firebase Crashlytics for our iOS project but I wasn't able to get valid crash log...

What I did so far:

1. Created a new "helloworld" iOS project
2. Added Firebase (Analytics & Crashlytics) by using SwiftPackageManager
3. Created the project within Firebase
4. Added the GoogleService-Info file
5. Called the init within the AppDelegate
6. Placed a button to force an unwrapping of a null value
7. Archived the project by using XCode & enterprise certificate
8. Located the archive and extracted the dSYM-file
9. Uploaded the dSYM-file by using the upload-symbols tool
10. Exported the archive as enterprise signed IPA
11. Installed the enterprise signed IPA on my device
12. Clicked the button and let the application crash

The crash is displayed within the firebase project and the section dSYM doesn't complain that some of the dSYM files are missing. Even though the crash isn't readable at all...

**Has anyone managed to display crashed in firebase with a comparable setup? Just found the information that sometimes it's necessary to uploading the dSYM file provided by App Store Connect (Which is impossible for my enterprise solution...)**

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: It looks like the crash has be desymobolicated as you can clearly see `ContentView`, I wouldn't think that you would be able to see that if it hadn't been successful. I think the problem could be with how the view is constructed, making it hard for where the crash occurs to be determined. Have you tried separating the view and the logic? Perhaps creating and using a ViewModel with the logic that causes the crash to see what outcomes you get?

Comment: I started with our own project. And first placed the crash within a rxswift closure with ended in an error like that. After that I thought mhhh could be some issue with the closure in the rxswift context and created a new method called forceCrash() and placed it somewhere else in the the IBAction connected with an storyboard but sadly I just saw the wrapping method like buttonClicked() and not the forceCrash() with wrong line numbers and content as well... So it seams like something is broken in firebase to me...

Comment: A similar question was answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65334819/4044241